# Hibernate native query INSERT of 100k records takes too much time

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate

I'm using Spring Boot 2.x, Spring DATA REST, Hibernate to create a REST server.
I created a import from a csv file of 100k records. Unfortunately I'm not able to reach decent values.
The import takes 150 seconds more or less.

The idea behind my code is to split data into smaller chunks (the best size in my test was 250) and create and commit a transaction for every chunk.

```
public int bulkInsert(Collection<OphthalmicLens> lenses) {
        StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch();
        StopWatch stopWatchQuery = new StopWatch();
        StopWatch stopWatchParameters = new StopWatch();
        stopWatch.start();
        int totalRecordsUpdated = 0;
        try {
            String insert = "INSERT INTO OphthalmicLens (`createdBy`,`createdDate`,`lastModifiedBy`,`lastModifiedDate`,`sid`,`version`,`manufacturer`,`manufacturerCode`,`name`,`sku`,`upc`,`cylinder`,`design`,`diameter`,`index`,`material`,`source`,`sphere`,`type`) VALUES ";
            String[] values = { "" };
            String onDuplicate = " ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE lastModifiedBy=VALUES(`lastModifiedBy`),lastModifiedDate=VALUES(`lastModifiedDate`)";
            // Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(insert);
            String createdBy = springSecurityAuditorAware.getCurrentAuditor().get();

            int i = 0;

            int chunkSize = 250;
            Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>(chunkSize);
            int chunkPage = 0;
            if (lenses.size() < chunkSize) {
                chunkSize = lenses.size();
            }

            for (i = 0; i < chunkSize; i++) {
                if (i > 0)
                    values[0] += ",";
                values[0] += "(:createdBy" + i + ",NOW(),:lastModifiedBy" + i + ",NOW(),UUID()" + ",:version" + i + ",:manufacturer" + i
                        + ",:manufacturerCode" + i + ",:name" + i + ",:sku" + i + ",:upc" + i + ",:cylinder" + i + ",:design" + i
                        + ",:diameter" + i + ",:index" + i + ",:material" + i + ",:source" + i + ",:sphere" + i + ",:type" + i + ")";
            }

            i = 0;
            int totalIndex = 0;
            for (OphthalmicLens lens : lenses) {
                params.put("createdBy" + i, createdBy);
                params.put("lastModifiedBy" + i, createdBy);
                params.put("version" + i, 1);
                params.put("manufacturer" + i, lens.getManufacturer());
                params.put("manufacturerCode" + i, lens.getManufacturerCode());
                params.put("name" + i, lens.getName());
                params.put("sku" + i, lens.getSku());
                params.put("upc" + i, lens.getUpc());
                params.put("cylinder" + i, lens.getCylinder());
                params.put("design" + i, lens.getDesign().toString());
                params.put("diameter" + i, lens.getDiameter());
                params.put("index" + i, lens.getIndex());
                params.put("material" + i, lens.getMaterial().toString());
                params.put("source" + i, lens.getSource().toString());
                params.put("sphere" + i, lens.getSphere());
                params.put("type" + i, lens.getType().toString());

                /**
                 * For every chunk I do a commit, flush and I clean entity manager
                 */
                if (i >= (chunkSize - 1) && i % (chunkSize - 1) == 0) {
                    transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallback<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public Void doInTransaction(TransactionStatus status) {
                            try {
                                Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(insert + values[0] + onDuplicate);
                                stopWatchParameters.start();
                                for (String key : params.keySet()) {
                                    query.setParameter(key, params.get(key));
                                }
                                stopWatchParameters.stop();
                                stopWatchQuery.start();
                                query.executeUpdate();
                                entityManager.flush();
                                entityManager.clear();
                                stopWatchQuery.stop();
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                log.error("", e);
                                status.setRollbackOnly();
                            }
                            return null;
                        }
                    });
                    params.clear();
                    // log.info("Query for chunk {} executed.", totalIndex / (chunkSize - 1));
                }

                i++;
                totalIndex++;

                // reset index when I change chunk page
                if (chunkPage != (i / chunkSize)) {
                    chunkPage = i / chunkSize;
                    i = 0;
                }

            }

        } finally {
            stopWatch.stop();
            log.info("Import completed in {} seconds.", stopWatch.getTotalTimeSeconds());
            log.info("Query time {} seconds.", stopWatchQuery.getTotalTimeSeconds());
            log.info("Setting params time {} seconds.", stopWatchParameters.getTotalTimeSeconds());
        }
        log.info("Total records updated: {}", totalRecordsUpdated);
        return totalRecordsUpdated;
    }
```

Every chunk create a query like this:

```
INSERT INTO OphthalmicLens (`createdBy`,`createdDate`,`lastModifiedBy`,`lastModifiedDate`,`sid`,`version`,`manufacturer`,`manufacturerCode`,`name`,`sku`,`upc`,`cylinder`,`design`,`diameter`,`index`,`material`,`source`,`sphere`,`type`) VALUES (?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,NOW(),?,NOW(),UUID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE lastModifiedBy=VALUES(`lastModifiedBy`),lastModifiedDate=VALUES(`lastModifiedDate`)
```

And this is a screenshot of Mysql logs that show how that queries are executed:

[image]

I tried to change batch_size with different values but result doesn't change so much.

This is the detail of where the time is consumed:

```
Import completed in 155.93 seconds.
Query time 89.901 seconds.
Setting params time 22.199 seconds.
```

I read many other posts about the topic and people claim to be able to insert also 100k rows in 10-20 seconds. I'm really far away from those values!

Do you have some advice to be able to accomplish the import in 10-20 seconds?

**p.s: I'm using Mysql 5.7 as db on a RDS free micro instance.**

Comment: Did you tried Spring Batch ?

Comment: @SeymurAsadov I didn't but I will give a look. Anyway I would like to fix my code to understand why it is not performing.

Comment: I‘m pretty sure you are not using batching as it‘s supposed to be used. Prepare ONE insert statement and reuse that one. Query parsing takes a considerable amount of time and the jdbc dricer cannot really optimize if the queries are always „different“. You don‘t need to fallback to native query necessarily. Just cleaning the entitymanager during the batch run should produce good results already, as the session does not need to hold (and scan) all the entities.